# Visual studio 2012 map::insert issue

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Iam new to vc++ .
I want to insert an array into map using map::insert()

`int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`
`{`

```
int arr[3] ={0,1,2};
map <int, int[3]> myMap;
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(1,arr));
```

return 0;

}

When I execute the code in visual studio 2012 Iam getting

`enter code here`error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::pair &&)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&'

Could you please tell me how get rid of this error..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a pair where it wants a map. Try the following example..

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>

    int main ()
    {
    std::map<char,int> mymap;

    // first insert function version (single parameter):
    mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('a',100) );
    mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',200) );

    std::pair<std::map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;
    ret = mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',500) );
    if (ret.second==false) {
    std::cout << "element 'z' already existed";
    std::cout << " with a value of " << ret.first->second << '\n';
    }

    // second insert function version (with hint position):
    std::map<char,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
    mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('b',300));  // max efficiency inserting
    mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('c',400));  // no max efficiency inserting

    // third insert function version (range insertion):
    std::map<char,int> anothermap;
    anothermap.insert(mymap.begin(),mymap.find('c'));

    // showing contents:
    std::cout << "mymap contains:\n";
    for (it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

    std::cout << "anothermap contains:\n";
    for (it=anothermap.begin(); it!=anothermap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

    return 0;
    }
```